# New Facebook API issue

Tags: facebook, api

Can anyone help me with this code and tell me what is wrong?

My code is not working anymore with the new Facebook API and I am getting the below errors!

```
Uncaught Error: OAuth2 specification states that 'perms' should now be called 
'scope'. Please update.

Error is in http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js line 23
```

And even if I changed it, it still does not work at all!

```
//THIS FUNCTION WILL INITIALIZE THE FACEBOOK API AND WILL ADD NEW FACEBOOK ACCOUNTS.
var apikey = $("#apikey").val();
//var tuittingID = $("#tuittingID").val();
FB.init({ apiKey: apikey, status : true, cookie : true, oauth: true });
FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);
$('#FBlogin').live('click', function() {
    FB.login(handleSessionResponse, {
        scope:'manage_pages, publish_stream, offline_access, user_status, 
        read_insights'
    });
    return false;
});
function handleSessionResponse(response) {
    if (!response.session || String(response.scope) == '') {
        return;
    }
    else
    var tuittingID = $.cookie("tuittingID");
    $('#AccessToken').val(response.session.access_token);
    $("#loader").show();
    $.post("tuitting/facebook_lib/fbadd.php",
    { tuittingID: tuittingID, uid: FB.getSession().uid, usid: 
    FB.getSession().session_key, accesstoken: response.session.access_token },
    function(data){
        reloadAccounts();
        $("#loader").hide();
        FB.logout(function(response) {
        }); //END LOGOUT FROM FACEBOOK AFTER SUCCESSFULL ACTION
    }
    ); //END AJAX POST FUNCTION DATA
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you make the changes needed to support Oauth 2? it's been mandatory since Oct 1st but the SDKs were only forced onto Oauth 2 yesterday (December 13 2012)

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/ - there's a summary of what changed and links to the announcing blog posts - the authentication and javascript docs are the docs you're most likely to need to check if you're making changes as this is where the changes were

Comment: The link pasted above has all the required information. If you are too lazy to read the page at above refer my answer below for the exact changes we did to make it work.

Comment: So what you're saying is you *did* update your app to oauth 2? you're still using response.session and response.session.uid in that sample code which implies you're not

Comment: Yes. I used response.session and response.session.uid to show what has changed from then to now. Also fixed the grammar to make it more contextual.

Comment: @user129206, if you're still using response.session, then you're NOT on oauth2.

Comment: response.session is not being used at all, even for somebody using it will get undefined against session. I just mentioned it in the example below for developers to be able easily see the difference and make the change.

Answer (score 1):

We were also affected by this change and we made the following changes to make it work. 
FB.init() was required as coded below with oauth set as true.

```
        FB.init({
        appId: 1234567890123,
        oauth: true
    })
```

And now there is no more session, **response.session** becomes **response.authResponse** and **response.session.uid** becomes **response.authResponse.userID**

```
            FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
                var postData = {
                    FBID: response.authResponse.userID,
                    Access_Token: response.authResponse.accessToken
                };
```

Link with additional information on js changes required
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you're using FB.getAuthResponse() instead of FB.getSession().

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Answer (score 0):

This is the Oauth 1.0 code:

**html**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_birthday" 
onlogin="afterFacebookConnect();" autologoutlink="false">Login con Facebook</div>
```

**javascript**

```
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'id_of_app',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true                });
        };


        if (document.getElementById('fb-root') != undefined) {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }


function afterFacebookConnect() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
            window.location = "/facebook/login?token=" + response.session.accessToken;
        } else {
            // user clicked Cancel
        }
    });
}
```

**Changes I made to adapt to Oauth 2.0:**

```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'id_of_app',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth:true // additional parameter
        });
    };

function afterFacebookConnect() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            window.location = "/facebook/login?token=" 
           + response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else {
            // user clicked Cancel
        }
    });
}
```

**Additional: Here is the code that handles the response (ASP.NET MVC, C#):**

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

```
   [RequireHttps]
    public ActionResult login(string token)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

            string JsonResult = client.DownloadString(string.Concat(
                   "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=", token));
            JObject jsonUserInfo = JObject.Parse(JsonResult);

            string nombre = jsonUserInfo.Value<string>("first_name");
            string segundo_apellido = jsonUserInfo.Value<string>("last_name");
            string nombre_completo = jsonUserInfo.Value<string>("name");
            string genero = jsonUserInfo.Value<string>("gender");
            string email = jsonUserInfo.Value<string>("email");
            string birthday = jsonUserInfo.Value<string>("birthday");

    // here you do your logic to login the user 
    // otherwise you can send user to the registration 
    // form and fill in some data you received from facebook

    }
```